# how to call variable in parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable `options` in controller.
I use directive `ng-sortable` which creates inner scope.
My html looks like:

```
<ul as-sortable ng-model="list">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" as-sortable-item>
    <i as-sortable-item-handle></i>
    {{ options.text }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I remove `as-sortable`, I can see `options.text`, because it searches it in correct scope.
But how to throw it inside that new scope?

UPDATE:

$parent.$parent.options.text gives me my variable.
But it looks ugly. Is there any better way (for avoiding calling of `$parent`)?

Comment: try `$parent.options.text`

Comment: I have tried, but it is not there also. Is there any way of direct binding?

Answer (score 0):

try '$scope.parentCtrlAsName' then assuming the parent controller is userCtrl in the child controller try:

```
var parent = $scope.userCtrl;
```

$scope.userCtrl gives you access to the parent controller scope.

Comment: It searches for a variable `userCtrl` in the current scope.

Comment: you can now call userCtrl.parentCtrlVariable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to have the child read its parent's scope, consider having the parent pass necessary data down to the child.

(The following may not be quite right, as I'm not certain where you're getting options.text from, but I hope the idea is clear enough:)

```
<ul as-sortable ng-model="list">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" as-sortable-item>
    <i as-sortable-item-handle myoptions="{{options.text}}"></i>
      {{ myoptions }}
  </li>
</ul>

.directive('asSortableItemHandle', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            myoptions: '@'
        }
        //...etcetera
    };
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is a third party directive

Comment: A controller overlay as suggested by @jideobi-benedine-ofomah is probably the way to go, then.